# APScheduler: How to schedule jobs with the identical function?

Tags: python, apscheduler

My goal is to schedule the same function (with different arguments) at different intervals/ dates. This is what I wrote so far (I'm using Flask APScheduler):

```
scheduler.add_job('date', paintCar, args=["red"], next_run_time=endsAtLocal)
```

If I run this, I get this error:

```
apscheduler.jobstores.base.ConflictingIdError: 'Job identifier (date) conflicts with an existing job'
```

Then I tried adding `replace_existing = True` when creating the job, which leads to not firing the function that was scheduled before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `BackgroundScheduler` from APScheduler. Now it does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message implies, you need to configure an explicit `id` for each job. If you use `replace_existing=True`, then you end up with just one job, not two as you wanted.